# What do you use to convert video to gif? Angular 9

Tags: angular

Does anyone have any idea what to use to convert Video to gif?
I am using angular 9 version.

Has anyone done this? Some paid service or something?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Cloudinary, it is free up to some extent
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/videos_to_animated_images

Answer (score 0):

iam use video.js for convert to video to gif

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).